# Unit testing IValueConverter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I have the custom converter, and i'd like to run unit-tests. I have basic test project [like this one](http://smartypantscoding.com/a-cheat-sheet-for-unit-testing-silverlight-apps-on-windows-phone-7), so i'm wondering, how should i make simplest unit tests for IValueConverter.

I already have 2 tests projects: one for integration tests (runs on the phone), second for unit tests (runs in console). Is it possible to test Converter as console app?

I had added converter as link to unit test project, made a test, but i'm facing several assembly references issues. Is there any sense to try to solve them?

Test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var conv = new DoubleToHPConverter();

        var result = conv.Convert(1500, typeof(string), null, null);

        Assert.AreEqual(result, "1.5K");
    }
}
```

Errors:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   Error 2   The type or namespace name 'IValueConverter' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error messages are clear IMO..

Comment: Yep, but is there a way, say, to ingore converter's usings in tests? As you, probably, noticed, converter is only about converting decimal to string.